# Best practices for treating Light Volumes in Deferred Lighting pipeline

Tags: opengl, glsl, lighting, pipeline, deferred-shading

This topic is about ways to handle light volumes in a deferred lighting pipeline.

I currently have a deferred lighting pipeline where spheres are sent to an openGL GLSL lighting shader. The sphere frags are shaded using my point and spotlight GLSL functions.

Currently, I calculate the radius/position of the volume sphere individually for each light and send it to the lighting shader which calculates accumulated light for every light in the scene for each frag in the sphere. So currently I am calculating number-of-lights * number-of-lights in my loop.

There must be a more efficient way to handle this for large volumes of lights. Two alternatives I can think of are:

Combine sphere volumes into a single buffer (especially easy if light positions are static) and make a single drawing call in which the shader iterates over all the spot and point lights for each frag.
Draw each volume separately and specify single lights to calculate for each volume. Many more drawing calls but calculations are limited to total-number-of-lights. I think this may be expensive for large volumes of lights, and I am always trying to reduce the number of my drawing calls.

Any thoughts specific or general appreciated.

Comment: I think the first option would be more efficient. There is a third option, which would be to use instancing: in the case of point lights, you would have the position and radius of the sphere as instance data. The benefit is that you wouldn't need to repeat the entire sphere vertices many times.